# Cannot get HTTP2 enabled on nginx 1.13 running with openSSL 1.0.2

Tags: nginx, http2

Im having a clue, Im trying to enable http2 on my website. I added it on my nginx.conf, I updated nginx from debian repository and added openSSL from another repo.

nginx -v :

```
nginx version: nginx/1.13.4
built by gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016 (running with OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

sources.list

```
deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
#deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
 deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-backports, from stretch-level but with no dependencies
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem today as well: it's because you are using the debian jessie variant of the nginx packages. If you use the ubuntu xenial variant instead, they will be compiled with OpenSSL 1.0.2g. You should still use the jessie-backports library to get OpenSSL 1.0.2l installed on your system.

`deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx`

`deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx`